# How to get json property when I use the Property Mediator?

Tags: wso2

I use the Property Mediator to get a registry resource, it returns me a json string, but how can I get the property in the json string?
my code example:

```
test-file.json like so
{
    "mappings": {
        "mapping": {
            "ep_1": "http://localhost:8280/services/ep_1",
            "ep_2": "http://localhost:8280/services/ep_2",
            "ep_3": "http://localhost:8280/services/ep_3"
        }
    }
}
```

I do like this:

```
<property expression="get-property('registry','conf:customresource/test-file.json')" name="JsonContent" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="????" name="endpointUrl" />
```

how to get the property 'ep_1' in the 'endpointUrl' Or is there any other way to get the property 'ep_1'? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with this question.You have to use XML content instead of JSON,  then set content into a Property Mediator which type filed is OM, and you can use xpath expression to get any value you want in your XML content.
code example

```
XML content:
<mappings>
    <mapping>
        <ep_1>http://localhost:8280/services/ep_1</ep_1>
        <ep_2>http://localhost:8280/services/ep_2</ep_2>
        <ep_3>http://localhost:8280/services/ep_3</ep_3>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

```
<property expression="get-property('registry','conf:customresource/test-file.xml')" name="XmlContent" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<property expression="$ctx:XmlContent/mapping/ep_1" name="endpointUrl" />
```

After that, the value will been set into the property named endpointUrl.
Last, please note the expression of second Property mediator,you get black value if you do like this $ctx:XmlContent/mappings/mapping/ep_1.Hope its helpful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

`expression="json-eval($ctx:JsonContent.mappings.mapping.ep_1)"`

If above does not work, try this.

`expression="$ctx:JsonContent//mappings/mapping/ep_1"`

Comment: both give you empty?

Comment: I tested in Integration Studio, the first one Integration Studio gives me an error note,and next one I got an empty value. I think the XPath will not work well because the property of JsonContent is json format, am i right?.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the input JSON to a property:

```
<property expression="json-eval($)" name="var_in_JSON" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

!!! **Don't use dots** (.) in the json property name !!!

...

Using data from a saved json property:

```
<property expression="json-eval($ctx:var_in_JSON.sub_param)" name="sub_param" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

The answer in your case:

```
<property expression="json-eval($ctx:JsonContent.ep_1)" name="ep_1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load json file from registry to payload, and make json-eval on payload. It is dirty solution, but it works ;):

```
<property expression="base64Decode(get-property('registry','conf:customresource/test-file.json'))" name="JsonContent" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<payloadFactory description="Build Payload Response" media-type="json">
  <format>$1</format>
  <args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:JsonContent" xmlns:payload="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property expression="json-eval($.mappings.mapping.ep_1)" name="endpointUrl" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Best regards

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this solution too, but there is a problem that the oraginal payload will be covered in this way, so I have to save the oraginal payload to another property before making json-eval on it. Indeed it`s not the best solution, but thanks all the same.